# PHPExcel large data sets with multiple tabs - memory exhausted

Tags: php, performance, phpexcel, large-data

Using PHPExcel I can run each tab separately and get the results I want but if I add them all into one excel it just stops, no error or any thing.

Each tab consists of about 60 to 80 thousand records and I have about 15 to 20 tabs. So about 1600000 records split into multiple tabs (This number will probably grow as well).

Also I have tested the 65000 row limitation with .xls by using the .xlsx extension with no problems if I run each tab it it's own excel file.

Pseudo code:

read data from db
start the PHPExcel process
parse out data for each page (some styling/formatting but not much)
(each numeric field value does get summed up in a totals column at the bottom of the excel using the formula SUM)
save excel (xlsx format)

<s>I have 3GB of RAM so this is not an issue</s> and the script is set to execute with no timeout.

I have used PHPExcel in a number of projects and have had great results but having such a large data set seems to be an issue.

Anyone every have this problem? work around? tips? etc...

UPDATE:

on error log --- memory exhausted

Besides adding more RAM to the box is there any other tips I could do?

Anyone every save current state and edit excel with new data?

Comment: Did you check your error log? What is php's memory limit? It's quite possible the script tries to allocate more ram than it's allowed.

Comment: crap on error log --- memory exhausted

Comment: You could just raise the memory limit to a point its working. If its a specific script i don't see it causing any problems on your machine. e.g. ini_set('memory_limit', '32M');

Comment: I have the same problem ... I write a spreadsheet to an xml file then convert to xls / xlsx using PHPExcel - fails on large files.... I have 32 GB of memory in my server and allocating 10 GB to it (PHP) - it fails to write large files even with this amount of memory !

Comment: That's not the physical memory, but the memory_limit set in your php.ini

Comment: I often have to work with data sets of over a million records. Usually, when I need to put stuff in excel when I have this much data I have my PHP output a delimited txt file and import that into excel itself. But this may not always work, especially if you include formatting and other fancy stuff in your spreadsheets.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, it is a memory issue with the PHPExcel library and physical memory is needed for this to work. I have set the memory limit in PHP to over 3GB and it's still an issue. After reading lots of posts about this on the PHPExcel forum this seems to be a limitation

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same problem and googling around did not find a valuable solution.

As PHPExcel generates Objects and stores all data in memory, before finally generating the document file which itself is also stored in memory, setting higher memory limits in PHP will never entirely solve this problem - that solution does not scale very well.

To really solve the problem, you need to generate the XLS file "on the fly". Thats what i did and now i can be sure that the "download SQL resultset as XLS" works no matter how many (million) row are returned by the database.

Pity is, i could not find any library which features "drive-by" XLS(X) generation.

I found this article on IBM Developer Works which gives an example on how to generate the XLS XML "on-the-fly": 
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-phpexcel/#N101FC

Works pretty well for me - i have multiple sheets with LOTS of data and did not even touch the PHP memory limit. Scales very well.

Note that this example uses the Excel plain XML format (file extension "xml") so you can send your uncompressed data directly to the browser.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats#Excel_XML_Spreadsheet_example

If you really need to generate an XLSX, things get even more complicated. XLSX is a compressed archive containing multiple XML files. For that, you must write all your data on disk (or memory - same problem as with PHPExcel) and then create the archive with that data. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML

Possibly its also possible to generate compressed archives "on the fly", but this approach seems really complicated.

Comment: Wow, Great Answer! I will have to give this a try and try to post back some results.

Comment: Thanks @kaii, Sorry I still have to test this out which could take a couple of weeks but if it does solve my problem I will make it as the accepted answer. Thanks again for your efforts, +1 was from me. And yes Example code is always welcome :)

Comment: not best quality code, but it gives you a rough example on how to do it: http://pastebin.com/k1LHbz3W

Comment: @PhillPafford may I ask you (now two years later) if you were able to solve your problem? did you possibly find a php-excel library that does not have this limitation?